# How to add new marker without removing previous marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am plotting markers from the long lat values from database. On the map, I can add markers to get the distance between two points. When I add new markers, the previously plotted marker from long lat values get disappear. I want to show previously plotted marker as it is even when I add new marker. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post your code...what actually you are doing...
May be you are doing clearmap while adding marker.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object instance for the new marker instead of changing the values of the old one.
If this isn't the solution, please consider editing your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).